# How to input null byte into bash script

Tags: c, bash

I am wrting a bash script that will pass a string argument to a C program. However the string I pass in must contain a null character but then when I try run the script I get `warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`

This is the script i'm trying to run:

```
echo -en $(python -c "print('b' * 10 + '$(echo '00' | sed 's/../\\x&/g')' + '\xe3\x45\x49\x43')") | /Security/buffer/prog1
```

The issue is with `$(echo '00' | sed 's/../\\x&/g')`. I have also tried just adding '\x00' or '\0' to the string with no luck.
How can I get around this limitation of bash so that I can pass in the null byte?

Comment: In C you can never have a string that contains a 0 byte. If you manage to provide some input that contains 0 in any position than after last character, this is no longer a string and you cannot treat it as a string in C. What problem do you try to solve with that approach?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe in more detail how exactly you want to pass the string/data (to `stdin` of a program?) and how exactly the string should look like. Is it a fixed string or does it contain variable parts? The program may ignore data after the first NUL (`'\0'`) character. Maybe you should use `printf` instead of `echo`. Or use the output of a Python script directly without Shell command substitution, e.g. `python -c '...' | /Security/buffer/prog1`

Comment: Thank you so much I can't believe I didn't think of actually not using echo.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `printf`. For example:

```
$ printf 'foo\x00\xe3\x45\x49\x43\n' | hexdump -C
00000000  66 6f 6f 00 e3 45 49 43  0a                       |foo..EIC.|
00000009
```